# Pi 3 cannot connect to Enterprise WiFi using GUI

Tags: wifi, pi-3, gui

Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running Raspbian "Jessie with PIXEL" (Release 2016-09-23).

It appears that all the WiFi networks that requires authentication other than a PSK are grayed out in the menu.

What is the reason behind this? Not supported by driver or not support by GUI?

Thanks!

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 12):

Turns out it is just the GUI that does not support WPA2 Enterprise. Was able to connect to those grayed-out networks by manually modifying `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` as follows:

```
network={
    ssid="VostroNet"
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    eap=TTLS   //put your EAP method
    identity="xxxxx"
    password="xxxxx"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPv2"
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Raspberry Pi! Thank you for comming back and providing an answer on your own. Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers I found online were obsolete, with the latest release of Raspbian. I made a post with the fix, [Connecting a Raspberry Pi 3 to Enterprise Wifi](https://hareshmiriyala.wordpress.com/2018/02/13/connecting-a-raspberry-pi-3-to-enterprise-wifi/):

> Type this in your terminal :
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
> ```
>
> Edit the contents of the file to the following :
>
> ```
> network={
>       ssid=""
>       priority=1
>       proto=RSN
>       key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
>       pairwise=CCMP
>       auth_alg=OPEN
>       eap=PEAP
>       identity=""
>       password=""
>       phase1="peaplabel=0"
>       phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
>       }
> ```
>
> Press Ctrl+O to save and Ctrl+X to exit.
>
> Fill in the blanks:
>
> - `ssid` with your University wifi’s ssid(name);
> - `identity` with your username, and;
> - `password` with your password.

Comment: Its not working for me.
I am trying to connect Raspberry pi in industry solution and using latest Raspbian Buster OS.
tried with wpa_supplicant option but does not work for cisco router with much of the parameter are not known to me.
Only sure that they are using WPA-EAP and username passowrd.

Answer (score 0):

For the eduroam environment in our university, the wpa_supplicant.conf looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=NL

network={
  ssid="eduroam"
  scan_ssid=1
  key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
  eap=PEAP
  identity="name@university.nl"
  password="MyPassword"
  phase1="peaplabel=0"
  phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```